# How to refresh/recompile custom preprocessor

Tags: unity-game-engine, preprocessor

I have a custom preprocessor in my PlayerSettings added to unity. According to unity documentation [Unity Custom Define Link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) basically you just add the preprocessor in

> **Player Settings->OtherSettings->Scripting Define Symbols**

and use that preprocessor in scripts **#if preprocessor**.
My problem is when I add it, the VS Editor does not change the code to compile enabled code and results in non complied code. Is there something else that I need to add to script after adding preprocessor. I have tried adding `AssetDatabase.Refresh();` to but it did not work. Is something needs to be refreshed in memory? I did restarted unity but did not helped.

---

Update: Now I have used the following script to add the preprocessor during runtime

```
/// <summary>
/// Symbols that will be added to the editor
/// </summary>
public static readonly string[] Symbols = new string[] {
    "MYPreprocessor1"
};

/// <summary>
/// Add define symbols as soon as Unity gets done compiling.
/// </summary>
static void AddDefineSymbols()
{
    string definesString = PlayerSettings.GetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(EditorUserBuildSettings.selectedBuildTargetGroup);
    List<string> allDefines = definesString.Split(';').ToList();
    allDefines.AddRange(Symbols.Except(allDefines));
    PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(
        EditorUserBuildSettings.selectedBuildTargetGroup,
        string.Join(";", allDefines.ToArray()));
}
```

The preprocessor blocks added via script works but I have to clear "**Scripting Define Symbols**" values and restarting unity allows the preprocessor block code to compile. But it wont work when you add it directly

Note: The above code adds the preprocessor blocks in to **Scripting Define Symbols** via scripting. If the preprocessor block is already existing it wont do anything else it will just add it.

Comment: Did you restart Visual Studio? I think that's all you have to do or simply reload the visual studio project.

Comment: Actually i have been reloading all VS and unity both but it doesnt refresh. It only works with above script that to first loading preprocessors and then restarting unity and again after clearing "Scripting Define Symbols" once from editor and one more restart after this. It is very weird. The preprocessor wont even work without above script if you directly add from Playersettings.

Comment: It works for me fine after reloading VS. Where are you calling `AddDefineSymbols()` from?

Comment: I call it from a custom class where i create some predefined settings for my project. The class is called from [InitializeOnLoad] so as soon as unity starts the constructor will be called and i can inititalise the project with some predefined settings. Yes as you said it should work fine strangely enough it wont. Let me check in empty project if it gives same problem

Comment: What's your Unity and Visual Studio version?

Comment: Im using 2017.2.0.p2 with VS community 2017. Btw even empty project has the same problem with preprocessor not getting enabled

Comment: Ok. We use the-same Unity version but different VS. Use VS2015. Run `UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility.RequestScriptReload();` after your code and see if that changes anything. Also run `UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.SaveCurrentModifiedScenesIfUserWantsTo();` and see if is a difference in behavior

Comment: I found the problem. The preprocessor block works only if you click on the 'Reload' button when VS notifies you. I used 'Reload Solution' which I assumed should almost be the same. So everytime i used reload solution it never updated preprocessor block. Only if you use just reload should update the preprocessor block and yes now it is working with manual and with scripted. One question pops up is isnt Reload & Reload Solution similer? How exactly they affect the preproccessor definitions? Let me check with those commands you mentioned if it works using Reload solution.

Comment: Update : I checked with above code and it wont work if you use reload solution. The only way to make it work is using reload option given by VS which is it reloads the updated project from disk only. I have a bad habit of reloading entire solution everytime. Maybe next time i should use reload more and reload solution less. Though iam still unaware how reloading solution affects the preprocessor compilation.

Comment: I don't know where you are seeing "'Reload Solution'". Mine says "Reload All" and that's what I've been using in VS. It should work.

Comment: The VS2017 gives me 4 options Reload, Reload Solution, Ignore & Ignore All. It only works with Reload that is first option.Using Reload Solution wont solve the problem on vs2017.

Comment: Then use "Reload". whichever works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this was a problem with Visual Studio 2017. The preprocessor would not work if you just do reload solution. Whenever a change in preprocessor statement was detected the VS would give four option Reload, Reload solution , Ignore and Ignore All. I was always using reload solution to reload all the data after change but for preprocessors to get activated/refreshed the first option in VS ie Reload button had to be pressed. With that you don't need to add any of the additional scripts above. I have tested with mono also and mono seems to do above work automatically. This was the case of VS2017 community. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

`AssetDatabase.Refresh` or `AssetDatabase.SaveAssets` should do the job without any manual steps, at least for JetBrains Rider.
Check in your preferences that Editor attaching is enabled.

Comment: Thanks ARMatt I already used AssetDatabase.Refresh. Have not tried yet with AssetDatabase.SaveAssets though. Yes i have Editor attaching enabled in preferences. I will have a look with AssetDatabase.SaveAssets in meantime and will post more information

Answer (score 0):

As ARMatt said, AssetDatabase.Refresh or AssetDatabase.SaveAssets, but I found in my case I needed both (saveassets first, but not sure if it matters). One or the other seemed to not retain the build info I was trying to store in the scriptable object.